# Network Stumbler (Fedora)Linux equivalent

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora

Does anyone know a linux equivalent to the [Network Stumbler](http://www.netstumbler.com/)? Some people recommend the [WiFi Radar](http://wifi-radar.berlios.de/), but I found it not nearly as functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want [**Kismet**](http://www.kismetwireless.net/). Kismet is basically "the" replacement for Network Stumbler on the Linux platform.

Kismet is included in the default Fedora software repositories.

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much.